# Adding a JTable to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to add  `test2` to my `DFrametest` class, so that the table of `test2` shows up in my window. I get an empty window and can't find the mistake.

```
public class test2 extends JPanel {

    JTable tbl;
    DefaultTableModel dt;

    public test2(){
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Course Lookup GUI");
        this.add( label );
        tbl = new JTable();
        dt = new DefaultTableModel();
        dt.addColumn("ID");
        dt.addColumn("Name");
        tbl.setModel(dt);

        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lagerverwaltungwin", "root", "");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT ArtNr, Beschreibung FROM artikel");  
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane();
        jp.getViewport().add(tbl);
        add(jp);
    }

}
```

This is my `Frameclass` which should have the table from `test2`:

```
public class DFrametest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DFrametest frame = new DFrametest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DFrametest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        test2 t = new test2();
        this.add(t);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never Use null Layout. Also donot use `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);`
use `pack();`

Change your `DFrametest` class like this

```
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Full Code of `DFrametest` class:

```
public class DFrametest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DFrametest frame = new DFrametest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DFrametest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        test2 t = new test2();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use setBounds() method since you haven't mentioned any layout (setLayout is null).
Add setBounds method before adding the jpanel to the jframe

```
setBounds(x-axis,y-axis,width,height);
```

EX:-

```
   setBounds(10,20,200,400);
```

Note:

Comment: I haven't suggeted it. It is OP's chopice. However , Just wondering how can we place some components at the specified/desired location.on the JFrame.Can you answer @Arijit

Comment: `"how can we place some components at the specified/desired location.on the JFrame"` Read [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: @user3505725 desired (J)Component at the specified/desired location isn't by default to specifics pixels location, for example starting with containers on resize